# How to use the SFTP drivers in october CMS

Tags: driver, sftp, octobercms, flysystem

Within octoberCMS there's a plugin called Drivers to install some third party drivers for storage; I want to use the SFTP drivers from FlySystem. I've adjusted the composer file of the driver plugin and added the flysystem;

```
   "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "composer/installers": "~1.0",

        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0",
        "pda/pheanstalk": "~3.0",
        "iron-io/iron_mq": "~1.5",
        "predis/predis": "~1.0",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0",

        "league/flysystem-rackspace": "~1.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",

        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.3",
        "league/flysystem-sftp":"~1.0"

    },
```

After installing the plugin the vendor folder contains also the flysystem-sftp files, but when I add an sftp record to the filesystems.php file in the config folder like

```
 'sftp' => [
                'driver'    => 'sftp',
                'host' => 'myftp.mydomain.com',
                'username'  => '########',
                'password'       => '########',
                'port' => '21',
                'passive'  => 'true',

            ],
```

October gives an error: "Driver [sftp] is not supported", when I try to use it. Is there any one who can help me further?

Comment: try after install package use composer dump command or regenerate autoloads ?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for your reply. I've tried, still not working via the filesystems.php. With this function in the driver plugin i'm able to use it and browse images via the mediamanager.

`public function boot()
    {
     Storage::extend('sftp', function($app, $config) {
     $adapter = new SftpAdapter([
       'host' => 'ftp.ftp',
        'port' => 22,
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
         'root' => '/',
         'timeout' => 10,
         'directoryPerm' => 0755]);
        return new Filesystem($adapter);
         
});`